# How do I reverse a case of each letter in a string?

Tags: go

I know about ToUpper and ToLower from strings package but obviously they won't help here. Is there a built-in function or do I have to write one myself?

Comment: Pretty sure you gotta write one yourself. It's pretty easy basic idea would be; get the ASCII value, if it's upper case subtract 26, if it's lower case add the same.

Comment: unless of course you have non-ascii characters. which you should expect to be able to handle: "Привіт, Світ!" isn't going to work that way

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to write one yourself, but the building blocks are already in the standard library:

```
func swapCase(s string) string {
    return strings.Map(func(r rune) rune {
        switch {
        case unicode.IsLower(r):
            return unicode.ToUpper(r)
        case unicode.IsUpper(r):
            return unicode.ToLower(r)
        }
        return r
    }, s)
}
```

Comment: Damn it @JimB, you're catching up to me, stop that!

Comment: Nice, elegant solution.

Comment: That looks really classy and elegant! Thank you. That will take me some time to wrap my head around though.